# Warning Message: Deleted branch skin (was ...)

Tags: git

From the man page for `git branch`:

> Delete a branch. The branch must be fully merged in its upstream branch, or in HEAD if no upstream was set with --track or --set-upstream.

```
$ git branch -d skin
warning: deleting branch 'skin' that has been merged to
     'refs/remotes/origin/skin', but not yet merged to HEAD.
Deleted branch skin (was 1f97b5b).

$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:me/Banana.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:me/Banana.git (push)
upstream    git@github.com:others/Banana.git (fetch)
upstream    git@github.com:others/Banana.git (push)
```

The *skin* branch was actually removed (locally) but I was trying to **understand what the warning message means**. Note the *skin* branch was still available at *origin* and *upstream*, as expected.

Comment: Maybe you haven't merged it into the current branch, locally?

Comment: I just checked out the `skin` branch from the origin for preview. I didn't mean to work on it locally. After that, I thought let's delete it rather than it sitting there doing nothing; thus, I came across this warning.

Comment: So it's not merged, and that's fine. It's just a warning, you can safely ignore it if it doesn't apply.

Comment: `Deleted branch skin (was 1f97b5b)` -- what does the SHA-1 inside the parenthesis refer to? An older commit?

Comment: It’s the commit `skin` pointed to. You could see what it is with `git show 1f97b5b` (assuming `git gc` hasn’t been run).

Comment: @minitech: even with a `git gc` the commit will still exist, as the complaint was just a warning. `remotes/origin/skin` contains (in the `git branch --contains` sense) `1f97b5b` (I'm assuming the remotes head still exists, of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning means just what it says: the branch name you asked git to delete is not an ancestor of `HEAD`.  Whatever branch you were on (e.g., `master`), `skin` named a commit that was not "part of" that branch.  But, the name `skin` was a tracking branch name, and it named a commit that was "part of" the origin tracking branch, so git removed the branch label.

The branch label used to point to commit `1f97b5b`.  It's likely that `origin/skin` *also* points (or pointed) to `1f97b5b`, i.e., the commit tree looked something like this:

```
A --- B --- C       <-- HEAD, master, origin/master
        \
          D --- E   <-- skin, origin/skin
```

where the SHA-1 of commit E is `1f97b5b`.  But it's possible that `skin` was a commit or more behind `origin/skin`, so that `1f97b5b` is the ID of commit D, or B, or even A.  The important thing is that starting from `origin/skin` it's possible to work backwards along the commit tree and find commit `1f97b5b`, therefore git figures that it is "safe" to delete a label pointing to commit `1f97b5b`.

Comment: I assume a "tracking branch" is the term for a branch that has a remote i.e. not a pure local branch?

Comment: Right, local branch L is "tracking" remote branch R (names need not match) if `git config branch.L.remote` is set to a remote name (like origin) and `git config branch.L.merge` has a ref name.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/how-do-you-make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch

Comment: I didn't know L and R do not need to have the same name. And, thanks (+1) for the link.